# Grant cross account access to dynamodb table without using sts:AssumeRole

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-access-policy, teleport

Essentially, I want an Iam role from AccountA to be able to manage a dynamodb table in AccountB, but the deployment that I am using does not support sts:AssumeRole (not my choice).  I faced this same issue with an S3, but I was able to add an S3 bucket policy that allowed the Iam role from AccountB to access it (see below).  Is there anything similar for dynamodb tables?

Thanks all :D

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountB:role/iam-role-name"
            },
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: DynamoDB does not at this time offer resource-based access control like S3 does.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that you can manage a table in another account is by assuming a role.

Unlike S3, DynamoDB does not support resource based access control. Unfortunately there are no simple workarounds as IAM is a security feature.